# Keyboard indicator lights appear after resuming from suspend

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, grub, keyboard, kubuntu

I used ubuntu 16 in my Sony Vaio SVE14133CVW for the past 3-4 years and it worked well. Just recently, I decided to install Mint 20 Mate. One problem that I faced was the keyboard stopped working when the laptop resumed from suspend. The touchpad and mouse worked fine though. Then, I changed in my /etc/default/grub the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"`

and its variant (including the `atkbd.reset`), sometimes with addition of `=1`, for example `atkbd.reset=1`. It was trials and errors. I did `sudo update-grub` and reboot once any change is made. The keyboard is now working but the laptop's keyboard indicator lights (numlock, caps lock etc) appear, and the "tap to click" has stopped working. I also faced the same problem when I tried Kubuntu 20 LTS. One thing that I realise is that a number of cases with similar issue come from Sony Vaio's laptops. Please let me know if your have any suggestion, and is it okay to revert back to old version of ubuntu (for example Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)?